# How to break a AWS map based on a condition

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, aws-step-functions

I have 10 elements in map. For each element I check some condition. If for any element,my condition passes,i want to break the map loop at that point. I don't want to loop further. I created 2 next states, one of Type succeed. Another of Type pass. But both are working same. In the succeed state,i want to break the loop. But that's not happening.

Answer (score 0):

As of now, breaking map is not supported in AWS.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).